# Create a field in Firebird which displays data from another table

Tags: sql, firebird

I didn't find a working solution for creating a "lookup column" in a Firebird database.

Here is an example:

Table1: Orders
[OrderID] [CustomerID] [CustomerName]

Table2: Customers
[ID] [Name]

When I run `SELECT * FROM ORDERS` I want to get OrderID, CustomerID and CustomerName....but CustomerName should automatically be computed by looking for the "CustomerID" in the "ID" column of "Customer" Table, returning the content of the "Name" column.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: is there no way to do this by creating a table, so that there is no need to join  tables later in every sql command? sorry for this stupid question, but i'm an absolute sql beginner

Comment: You would create a view which can be used like a table for selects statements.

Comment: Thank, this solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebird has [calculated fields](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-computedby) (`generated always as`/`computed by`), and these allow selecting from other tables (*contrary to an earlier version of this answer, which stated that Firebird doesn't support this*).

However, I suggest you use a view instead, as I think it performs better (haven't verified this, so I suggest you test this if performance is important).

### Use a view

The common way would be to define a base table and an accompanying [view](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-view) that gathers the necessary data at query time. Instead of using the base table, people would query from the view.

```
create view order_with_customer
as
select orders.id, orders.customer_id, customer.name
from orders
inner join customer on customer.id = orders.customer_id;
```

Or you could just skip the view and use above join in your own queries.

### Alternative: calculated fields

I label this as an alternative and not the main solution, as I think using a view would be the preferable solution.

To use calculated fields, you can use the following syntax (note the double parentheses around the query):

```
create table orders (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
    customer_id integer not null references customer(id),
    customer_name generated always as ((select name from customer where id = customer_id))
)
```

Updates to the `customer` table will be automatically reflected in the `orders` table.

As far as I'm aware, the performance of this option is less than when using a join (as used in the view example), but you might want to test that for yourself.

#### FB3+ with function

With Firebird 3, you can also create calculated fields using a trigger, this makes the expression itself shorter.

To do this, create a [function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-psql-funcs.html) that selects from the customer table:

```
create function lookup_customer_name(customer_id integer) 
    returns varchar(50)
as
begin
    return (select name from customer where id = :customer_id);
end
```

And then create the table as:

```
create table orders (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
    customer_id integer not null references customer(id),
    customer_name generated always as (lookup_customer_name(customer_id))
);
```

Updates to the `customer` table will be automatically reflected in the `orders` table. This solution can be relatively slow when selecting a lot of records, as the function will be executed for each row individually, which is a lot less efficient than performing a join.

### Alternative: use a trigger

However if you want to update the table at insert (or update) time with information from another table, you could use a [trigger](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-trgr).

I'll be using Firebird 3 for my answer, but it should translate - with some minor differences - to earlier versions as well.

So assuming a table `customer`:

```
create table customer (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null
);
```

with sample data:

```
insert into customer(name) values ('name1');
insert into customer(name) values ('name2');
```

And a table `orders`:

```
create table orders (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
    customer_id integer not null references customer(id),
    customer_name varchar(50) not null
)
```

You then define a trigger:

```
create trigger orders_bi_bu 
    active before insert or update
    on orders
as
begin
    new.customer_name = (select name from customer where id = new.customer_id);
end
```

Now when we use:

```
insert into orders(customer_id) values (1);
```

the result is:

```
id  customer_id  customer_name
1   1            name1
```

Update:

```
update orders set customer_id = 2 where id = 1;
```

Result:

```
id  customer_id  customer_name
1   2            name2
```

The downside of a trigger is that updating the name in the `customer` table will not automatically be reflected in the `orders` table. You would need to keep track of these dependencies yourself, and create an after update trigger on `customer` that updates the dependent records, which can lead to update/lock conflicts.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very informative. Based on your recommendation i will use a view.

Comment: @Arioch'The Firebird doesn't allow it in 2.5, 3.0 and 4.0; I didn't look farther back. Although looking at your example, I didn't try with double parentheses.

Comment: Mark, this DOES work in FB 2.1 :-D / Sure, the syntax is quirky. You just have to remember that computed-by column takes an `expression` inside the column declaration parentheses. And that a singular `select` stmt is converted into an `expression` by putting it inside parentheses as well (consider `update ... set a = (select...)` - that is the same principle). You just had to connect the dots and deploy BOTH paren. pairs - one for column decl and one for `expression` convertion  /// not that I would recommend it for practical use, of course. VIEW is the correct starting direciton

Comment: @Arioch'The Just checked, in Firebird 3 double parentheses work as well. Will revise my answer.

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to highlight behavior/resultset difference between join and computed-by-select approaches, when instead of singular lookup result there would be many rows or none.

Answer (score 0):

No need here a complex lookup field.
No need to add a persistant Field [CustomerName] on Table1.

As Gordon said, a simple Join is enough :

```
Select T1.OrderID,  T2.ID,  T2.Name
From Customers T2 
Join Orders T1 On T1.IDOrder = T2.ID
```

That said,  if you want to use lookup Fields (as we do it on a Dataset)  with SQL you can use some thing like :

```
Select T1.OrderID,  T2.ID,  
( Select T3.YourLookupField From T3 where (T3.ID = T2.ID)  )
From Customers T2 Join Orders T1 On T1.IDOrder = T2.ID
```

Regards.